# Unity Video Overlay Issues

Tags: google-project-tango

I have used the ARScreen.cs script and ar_screen shaders from the AugmentedReality scene provided in getthehub.

The GUI shows perfectly, the background/Video Overlay displays perfectly but everything else draws over the video and stains. Video Overlay and GPU Acceleration options are enabled on Tango Manager, Ux script is enabled but its options are disabled.

Any advice regarding having the 3d objects render normal (exactly like the markups in the unity example project)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Enable Ux script's options, set the culling of the main camera, the camera you are using for your arscreen.cs script to solid color white, and then in the arscreen.cs I commented out the command/call //_UpdateTransformation(timestamp); in my case... apparently the _UpdateTransformation command placed my camera far from the player's object and thus objects were not visible and it seemed as if the video overlay covered my seen.